# sum all columns in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
CREATE TABLE onecanteen (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Items_wholesale CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Items_retail CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Ammount_recive CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
items_quantity Char(30)NOt Null,
)
```

insert data :

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-save']))
{
    $wholesale = $_POST['Items_wholesale'];
    $retail = $_POST['Items_retail'];
    $quantity = $_POST['items_quantity'];
    $recive = $_POST['Ammount_recive'];

    if($crud->create($wholesale,$retail,$quantity,$recive))
    {
        header("Location: add-data.php?inserted");
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: add-data.php?failure");
    }
}
?>
```

begnier in php 
create/read/update/delete  Normally data is stored in MySQL Database
after storing data i perform following mathematics operation as mention below while fetch data

```
<td>            <?php print($row['id']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row['Items_wholesale']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row['Items_retail']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row['items_quantity']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row['Ammount_recive']); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Items_retail'] * $row['items_quantity'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Items_wholesale'] * $row['items_quantity'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo ($row['Items_retail'] * $row['items_quantity'] )-($row['Items_wholesale'] * $row['items_quantity'])  ?></td>
```

here i see all my record

```
<!-- showing whole record add delet record  -->
<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="container">
<a href="add-data.php" class="btn btn-large btn-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> &nbsp; Add Records</a>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div><br />

<div class="container">
     <table id="table1" class='table table-bordered table-responsive'>
     <tr>
     <th >#</th>
     <th >Wholesale</th>
     <th >retail</th>
     <th >Quantity</th>
     <th >wholesale total</th>
     <th >Retail total</th>
     <th >profit</th>
     <th >Recive ammount </th>
     <th colspan="2" align="center">Actions</th>


     <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM onecanteen";
        $records_per_page=3;
        $newquery = $crud->paging($query,$records_per_page);
        $crud->dataview($newquery);
     ?>
    <tr>
```

program working perfectly fetch data from  onecanteen table 
now i want to sum all column hlpe me how i can do it   ??

Comment: Sum all column ? What you mean by that, what are the column data ? you can sum only numbers. Can you explain what you trying to achieve by that "SUM" ?

Comment: all inputs are numbers

Comment: What should the result be? 

Each column separately? Or all together?

Comment: yes !! each column separately total ..

Answer (score 0):

To calculate total amount of data in each column separately you can use:

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) as sum1, SUM(column_name1) as sum2 FROM ....
```

Comment: i modified my question hope you understand it better now